# Find a basis for two operators

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $(E, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be an $n$-dimensional Hilbert space and $A,B \colon E \to E$ linear isomorphisms.

Does there exist a basis $\{e_{1},...,e_{n}\}$ of $E$ such that $\mathcal{A}=\{A(e_{1}),...,A(e_{n})\}$ and $\mathcal{B}=\{B(e_{1}),...,B(e_{n})\}$ are orthogonal bases?

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: @levap what's an $n$-dimensional Hilbert?  I'm only aware of a $3$-dimensional Hilbert.  Also, why replace `:` with `\colon`?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I've lost the space... fixed. Regarding the $\colon$, I prefer the spacing obtained using colon over :. It seems that colon is used more often in textbooks and articles.

Comment: @levap I definitely have the opposite preference, but to each his own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true. Define a new inner product $g(v,w)$ on $E$ by the formula $g(v,w) := \left< Av, Aw \right>$ and let $\beta(v,w) := \left< Bv, Bw \right>$ (this is another inner product on $E$ but what is important that it is a symmetric bilinear form). Then you can find an **orthonormal** basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ of $(E,g)$ such that with respect to this basis, $\beta$ is diagonal. That is,

$$ g(e_i, e_j) = \left<Ae_i, Ae_j \right> = \delta_{ij},  \\
\beta(e_i,e_j) = \left<Be_i, Be_j \right> = \delta_{ij}, \,\,\,  i \neq j.
$$

Thus, $(Ae_1, \dots, Ae_n)$ is $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$-orthonormal and $(Be_1,\dots,Be_n)$ is $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$-orthogonal. Note that $e_1,\dots,e_n$ won't necessarily be $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$-orthogonal.

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not see your answer while typing.

Comment: @levap how are you *defining an inner product* on $E$?  The inner product is given with the space.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The two new inner products levap defines are built using the one $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ given in the original space.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: No problem.

Comment: @angryavian why are we talking about two different spaces?  As far as I can tell, there's only one space $E$ with one inner product.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: It might be easier to think of the case $A = \operatorname{Id}$ first. Then the question asks whether we can find an orthogonal basis $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ of $(E, \left< \cdot, \cdot \right>)$ (the original inner product space) such that $(Be_1, \dots, Be_n)$ is $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$-orthogonal. The answer is yes, because we can diagonalize the quadratic form $\beta(v,w) = \left< Bv, Bw \right>$ $\left<\cdot, \cdot \right>$-orthonormally.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: For a general $A$, since $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ is not required to be $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$-orthogonal, we "replace" the original inner product with a new inner product defined using $A$ and $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$ and apply the same argument.

Comment: @levap I see my mistake! I thought $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ had to be orthogonal

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry I meant the inner product in the original definition $(E,\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle)$. Levap is constructing two new inner products on the same space $E$.

Answer (score 3):

We define the following two inner products on $E$

$$ \langle v, w\rangle_A:=\langle Av, Aw \rangle \qquad \langle v, w\rangle_B:=\langle Bv, Bw \rangle.$$

Your question is now, whether there exists a basis $\{ e_1, \dots, e_n \}$ which is orthogonal with respect to both inner products. This is true and is proven here

[Show that a Hilbert space with two inner products has a basis that is orthogonal with respect to both inner products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772629/show-that-a-hilbert-space-with-two-inner-products-has-a-basis-that-is-orthogonal?rq=1)

Comment: Why are we defining different inner products on $E$?  The space $E$ is given along with an inner product on that space.

Comment: I knew the later fact I quoted and defined those inner products to reduce the question to the fact.